# If $f''$ is uniformly continuous and $f$ converges to $0$ then $f'$ converges to $0$

Tags: limits, derivatives, uniform-continuity

Let $f : (0, +\infty) \rightarrow \Bbb R$, $f''$ is uniformly continuous and $f$ converges to $0$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$. Show that $f'$ converges to $0$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$.

To be honest, I do not know how to do this, the only thing I know is that $f$ must also be uniformly continuous. How can I prove this?

Comment: Where did you get this question from? The result holds if $f''$ is bounded, however it is not possible to prove the boundedness of $f''$ using uniform continuity as the interval $(0, \infty) $ is unbounded.